# Reduce size of sub images in tikz/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I had created an tikz image using matlab2tikz, as seen below:

[image]

I would like to reduce the size of the individual spheres while keeping the dimensions of the overall image constant, essentially inserting some white space between each sphere. My code is too large to display directly, so I shall provide a link to the tikz file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gr5wsnnnjzztwsh/SH1.tikz?dl=0

The code looks intimidatingly long but is essentially a series of axis environments with coordinates for the individual spherical harmonics.

Comment: You could just use use the first two rows as an MWE.  Anyway, if you can add more space between the spheres, you can use \resizebox{\textwidth}{!} (graphicx package) over the whole thing.

Comment: Still wondering about this? You can try expanding the axis limits a bit, by saying something like `[/pgfplots/every axis/.append style={enlargelimits=0.2}]`. This will add some whitespace around the sphere in each axis, hence making them smaller. Then you may want to increase `\figureheight` and `\figurewidth` a bit to make larger again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added whitespace between the image by adding `xshift` and `yshift` to certain axis environments, depending on where I needed the space. This was quite difficult as many of environments are anchored to other environments.The image: [image]

A link to my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mutzlu1tmrf2hg/SH1.tikz?dl=0